# Ruby on Rails: patching Rack and deploying it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I need to patch Rack with the following patch: http://github.com/rack/rack/commit/dae12e088592ee69545b5f2f81b87f4959859164

What's the best practice for doing this? Should I gem unpack, apply the patch, then repack the gem and ship it with capistrano to make sure my version of the gem gets to the destination server?

can I just pop rack into vendor/plugins/ and rely on it being loaded first prior to the system wide gem?

I want to take the path of least resistance and easily be able to deploy this to many environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install gems from a repository using `bundler` if you're using that by adding an option to your Gemfile:

gem 'rack', :git => 'git://github.com/my-account/rack.git'

This makes patching and deploying patched gems a lot easier. Fork it to your account, patch it, and use that base instead.

Rack isn't a plugin, it's a gem, so it probably won't work properly if installed in `vendor/plugins`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of pointing to your git repository, you can have Bundler load from a local filesystem, like a `vendor/` subdirectory:

```
gem 'rack', :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/rack')
```

That allows you to debug on the fly without having to git pull / push your changes.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers appear to require Bundler/Rails 3. Since I'm using Rails 2.3.10 and the old-style Rails config.gem system, they didn't work for me.

I was able to find a working solution for this same problem [here](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/7/15/rails-2-3-8-rack-1-1-and-the-curious-case-of-the-missing-quotes). The author included the fixed code from Rack 1.2 in a [monkey patch for rack 1.1](https://gist.github.com/477631), and then loaded the patch file through an initializer.